# Python - how to copy object (so it would not reference old object) without using deepcopy?

Tags: python, reference, copy

I have this code:

```
import pygame
import block as b
import constants as c
import copy
def walls():
    walls_list = []

    wall_proto = b.Wall(c.WHITE, 40, 40, 20, 80)
    wall = copy.copy(wall_proto)
    wall.rect_x = 50
    print wall_proto.rect_x
    print wall.rect_x

walls()
```

prints:

```
50
50
```

But I want to print it

```
40
50
```

I want to create various 'walls' in my game. And those walls maybe have lots of similar data, but some different too. So I want to have some wall object that could be used to copy from and then set different properties on different walls. If I use simple copy, then if I change anything in copied object, all other objects will change that value too. I can use deepcopy, but it is very slow. Is there workaround/better solution than deepcopy?

**Update**

As requested Wall class:

```
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        #to get/set values
        self._width = width
        self._height = height

    @property
    def rect_x(self):
        return self.rect.x
    @property
    def rect_y(self):
        return self.rect.y
    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width
    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._height

    @rect_x.setter
    def rect_x(self, value):
        self.rect.x = value

    @rect_y.setter
    def rect_x(self, value):
        self.rect.y = value

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        self._width = value

    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        self._height = value
```

Comment: Why are you averse to using `deepcopy`?

Comment: Because it is slow. If I only rely on deepcopy, later it may reduce performance. So I am hoping there are some other solutions, that may have better performance.

Comment: Could you show the definition of `Wall`, or even better create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? The obvious definition should *not* lead to the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: What is the nature of ``wall_proto`` please ?

Comment: Why don't you write ``wall = b.Wall(c.WHITE, 50, 40, 20, 80)`` ? The second argument is 50 instead of 40. But even if it was the same, I think the instance named ``wall`` would be a different object than the instance named ``wall_proto``

Comment: Yeah I can do that, but wanted to avoid writing same thing if I needed only one parameter changed. But maybe it is almost the same as to write that or to write another line setting some value

Comment: According to the name ``wall_proto`` it seems that you create the instance named ``wall_proto`` to keep it as a prototype to create other instances based on it. It appears to me that it is perverting the OOP model in which, if one needs an instance, this one is created from a class, not by creating from an other instance used as a pattern.

Comment: What's the problem of writing a nearly-similat line ? It sounds as if you were annoyed to have to create an other instance. Either you need an other instance, either you don't. You can't conceive an algorithm without using the elements constituing this algorithm ! Maybe if you aren't satisfied, it is a problem of algorithm, in fact ? I have an idea concerning this point of view. I'll post an answer

Comment: What is the instance ``wall_proto`` intended to be used to ? Is it just to keep the original values of ``self.rect.x``, ``self.rect.y``, ``self._width`` and ``self.height`` , or to be plainly used as an instance ? The idea I had is so simple-minded in the first case, and useless in the second case, that it doesn't deserves to be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

1. change all arguments to keyword arguments,
2. add a `wall=` keyword arg to the Wall constructor.
3. If `wall` is set, copy the values into the new instance, then set them according to the other parameters. Like so:

   ```
   class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       def __init__(self, color=None, x=None, y=None, width=None, height=None, wall=None):
           pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
           # check parameters are valid
           assert any([color and x and y and width, wall]), "invalid arguments"
           # assign parameters from given wall or parameters
           x      = x or wall.rect_x
           y      = y or wall.rect_y
           color  = color or wall.color
           height = height or wall.height
           width  = width or wall.width
           ...
   ```

   Then you can write code like:

   ```
   wall1 = Wall(c.WHITE, 40, 40, 20, 80)
   wall2 = Wall(color=c.BLUE, wall=wall1)
   ```

Comment: Cool, I did the similar thing myself :)

Answer (score 0):

if it's a simple list (without any mutable objects), you can use: List[:] or Dict.copy()

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this just isn't how you should be doing this. Consider instead making a `classmethod` that will define whole ranges of walls at once. Something like...

```
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        # since your properties are only getters and setters, don't use them
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    @classmethod
    def make_walls(cls, color, coords):
        """Makes a grouping of walls of a specified color, given
        a list of (x, y, width, height) tuples"""
        list_of_walls = []
        for details in coords:
            x, y, width, height = details
            wall = cls(color, x, y, width, height)
            list_of_walls.append(wall)
        return list_of_walls
        # or MUCH less clear:
        # return [cls(color, *details) for details in coords)]
```

Then you can make any walls you like by doing:

```
wall_locations = [
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1, 1),
    (1, 3, 1, 1),
    (1, 4, 1, 1),
    ... ]
new_walls = b.Wall.make_walls(c.WHITE, wall_locations)
```